How to disable/enable startup programs through Registry Editor
Hey im working on a windows tweaker program. As we all know, startup programs can commonly be found in the task manager where we can either enable or disable them. The location of those programs are found in different parts of the registry editor such as: Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run. However, i dont know how to disable them in the registry editor without using the task manager. It is important to say that deleting the key is useless because some programs create this key again. What i need is just like a task manager, where i can disable them but without deleting them
I tried by searching the web and the registry editor but i found nothing. Any ideas?
Thanks a lot.

My conclusion after some time is that I recommend to change those values within the task manager itself. However is safe to remove them as well to be completely sure it won't startup again if desired.
Having said thas, I did a PowerShell (.ps1) script that displays all the DWord keys found in those locations of the Registry to have more control over the startup items. Anyhow, you can only see them, but not change them. The github proyect is in the following link: https://github.com/MartinLXXX6/Windows-Controller-Tool. Just navigate to the releases part at the lower-right corner of the page and download the first file (.ps1) and follow the readme instructions on how to run the script.

informations about allowed or not processes are stored here :
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StartupApproved


Thats right, however when i disable a application is not removed from there, instead the value changes. Anyone knows the meaning of the values. Also, the following values i think means that is enabled: 02 00 00 ...... and 06 00 00 .....
Any knowledge?

And how can i tell if the key value must be 06 00.... or 02 00... to be enabled with a program?
